# Failed to construct 'FormData' error appeared

Tags: javascript, ajax, phpmailer

Something wrong is going on with my contact form. Just recently everything was fine but now I can't send the message.
When I try to submit the form I see this error now:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not
>   of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
>       at submitForm (ajax.js:77)
>       at HTMLFormElement. (ajax.js:72)
>       at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
>       at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#subscribeForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Are you sure you filled form inputs correctly?");
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});
function submitForm(){
            var subscribe_email =$("input[name=subscribe_email]").val();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            formData.append('subscribe_email', subscribe_email );
            $.ajax({
                 url: "include/ajax/subscribe.php",
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                 data: formData,
                 cache: false,
                 success : function(text){
             if (text == "success"){
                 formSuccess();
             } else {
                 formError();
                 submitMSG(false,text);
             }
         }
     });
 }
function formSuccess(){
    $("#subscribeForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG("valid", "Your message was successfully sent");
}
function formError(){
  submitMSG("invalid", "Something went wrong. Please, try again or contact with our support team.");
}
function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "cf-alert alert success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "cf-alert alert warning";
    }
    $("#success_submit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What's wrong and why did it suddenly break? Thanks so much in advance, folks.

Comment: Try to log `this` inside `submitForm`. Should be `window` or `undefined` in strict-mode because you call this function without binding it anywhere, nor as being a method of anything (`submitForm()`). Now, try to guess what will be `$(this)[0]` here.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't help. The error now says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: @Jamdev you were not offered a solution so it's not surprising that it didn't work. You were asked to do some debugging so you can figure out for yourself what the problem is

Comment: Within your `.on('submit', ...)` handler, `this` will refer to the `<form>` so how about passing that to your `submitForm` function, eg `submitForm(this)` and `function submitForm(form) { ... }` where you can use `form` instead of `$(this)[0]`

Comment: @Phil thank you so much, friend. You are a genius!

Answer (score 6):

The error states it pretty cleary.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'. at submitForm (ajax.js:77) at HTMLFormElement. (ajax.js:72) at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183) at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)

`var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); // $(this)[0] is not a form element`
In your code `$(this)[0]` is bound to the global object(window in a browser)

You could pass a reference to your form like this:

```
$("#subscribeForm").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm(this);
});

function submitForm(myForm){
    const formData = new FormData(myForm);
    // or like this
    // const myForm = document.getElementById("subscribeForm");
    // const formData = new FormData(myForm);

}
```

In your case you can call the FormData constructor without any parameters since your doing formData.append()

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("some_key", "some_value");
```

You can read more about formData [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: "*In your case you can call the FormData constructor without any parameters since your doing formData.append()*" **No**, `append` don't remove what's been set at initialization. They should keep it if they need the form's data (which is highly probable).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your line:

```
//var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

The solution is simple:

```
var formData = new FormData();
```

after this append anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is another element with same id as the form #subscribeForm